# Using function parameter in jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object named path which is:

```
var path = { "firstFloor": ["roomA1", "roomA6", "roomA5", "roomA2", "roomA3", "roomA4", "roomA10"],
  "secondFloor": ["roomB4", "roomB5", "roomB6"],
  "basementFloor": []}
```

right now I'm selecting the arrays normally (path.firstFloor etc.), but I need to select these pairs in a function with the key as the parameter, so:

```
function draw(floor) { //later on I will call this function with parameter firstFloor
  $(path.floor).each(function(i, val){ //this is where I need to select.
    var roomIdPath = path.firstFloor[i]
    //console.log(roomIdPath);
    var points = d3.select('#'+roomIdPath).attr('points').split(",");
    var midX = (Number(points[0]) + Number(points[6])) / 2;
    var midY = (Number(points[1]) + Number(points[3])) / 2;
    floorArray.push({"x": midX, "y": midY});
  });
}
```

Not sure if I'm being clear, basically, all I need is a way to use function parameter in jQuery selector. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are sending keys to function you can use the keys to access values mapped against the key in the object path.

Currently you have used `path.floor`, this is wrong as it will look for a key named floor inside path object you need to use `path[floor]`. you can do something like this:

```
 function draw(floor) { //later on I will call this function with parameter firstFloor
      $(path[floor]).each(function(i, val){ //this is where I need to select.
        var roomIdPath = path[floor][i];
        //console.log(roomIdPath);
        var points = d3.select('#'+roomIdPath).attr('points').split(",");
        var midX = (Number(points[0]) + Number(points[6])) / 2;
        var midY = (Number(points[1]) + Number(points[3])) / 2;
        floorArray.push({"x": midX, "y": midY});
      });
    }
```

Comment: typically would use `$.each` instead of `$.fn.each`. No need to wrap arrays in `$()`

Comment: @charlietfl can you say reasons for your preference? as both give same result.

Comment: Readability is one... `$.each(array/obj..` is clearly not dom related vs `$(array)` which is. Also internally `$(array)` does another `each` internally

Answer (score 0):

try bracket notation `path[floor]` instead, the parameter will be a value not a variable, and don't forget to use `console.log(variable)` occassionally for debugging purposes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the question right:
You can iterate over the keys of your elements (with the caveats that floors might be an object with additional properties in the prototype):

```
for(floor in floors){
    //do your thing
}
```

or better with Jquery:

```
$.each(floors, function(key, value){
    //do the thing you were doing in the question
    //key is your floor name, value is your array of rooms
});
```